# How do I turn a square signal into a triangular signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to turn the square signal below into a triangular signal. How do I do that? I have tried to do it using the sawtooth/square functions but I have to do it without using those (Also, sawtooth is not triangular, so there goes that). I have managed to write the code for a square signal but I don't know what exactly to change in order for it to be triangular.

```
P=40; 
D=12; 
N=50; 
f=1/P; 
w0=2*pi*f; %angular frequency
rez=0.1; %signal's temporal resolution

s1=[ones(1,D/rez),zeros(1,(P-D)/rez)]; %a period of the square signal
t=0:rez:P; %equivalent time for a period
perioada=P/rez;%number of samples in a period
inter1=0:rez:P;
stem(inter1(1:400),s1)
title('Square Signal x(t)'),
xlabel('t[s]')
ylabel('A')

semnal=repmat(s1,1,5);%initial signal repeated 5 times
figure
plot(semnal)
title('5 periods from the signal')
xlabel('t[s]')
ylabel('A')
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a [Triangular pulse function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/triangularpulse.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a triangular `s1` by building left triangle side, right triangle side and connect both sides.

Build left side using [linspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) from `1` to `0` with `D/rez+1` points:

```
s1_left = linspace(1, 0, D/rez+1);
```

Build right side using [linspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) from `0` to `1` with `(P-D)/rez+1` points:

```
s1_right = linspace(0, 1, (P-D)/rez+1);
```

Concatenate left part and right part (use `1:end-1` for smooth transition)

```
s1 = [s1_left(1:end-1), s1_right(1:end-1)];
```

Here is the complete (updated) code:

```
P=40; 
D=12; 
N=50; 
f=1/P; 
w0=2*pi*f; %angular frequency
rez=0.1; %signal's temporal resolution

%s1=[ones(1,D/rez),zeros(1,(P-D)/rez)]; %a period of the square signal

s1_left = linspace(1, 0, D/rez+1);  %Left size of triangle
s1_right = linspace(0, 1, (P-D)/rez+1); %Right size of triangle
s1 = [s1_left(1:end-1), s1_right(1:end-1)]; %Concatenate left part and right part (use 1:end-1 for creating smooth connection).

t=0:rez:P; %equivalent time for a period
perioada=P/rez;%number of samples in a period
inter1=0:rez:P;
stem(inter1(1:400),s1)
title('Square Signal x(t)'),
xlabel('t[s]')
ylabel('A')

semnal=repmat(s1,1,5);%initial signal repeated 5 times

figure
plot(semnal)
title('5 periods from the signal')
xlabel('t[s]')
ylabel('A')
```

Result:
[image]

Square signal and triangular signal in the same plot:
[image]